# writing csv gives results splitted wrongly

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write the elements of a vector in a csv file. These are the first  3 elements of the vector called questao (questao is a dict initiated as questao = {}):

```
A titulação genérica de Administração Pública, usada pelo legislador constituint
e de 1988, ao tratar da Organização do Estado, para efeito de sujeição dos seus
atos à obediência de determinados princípios fundamentais e à observância de out
ras exigências, restrições ou limitações ali declinadas, abrange e alcança

O regime jurídico administrativo, posto em relação com o direito privado, acarre
ta a assertiva de que

A natureza do regime jurídico único dos servidores públicos federais é de ordem
predominantemente
```

I printed it with this code:

```
>>> for i in range(0,3):
...  print questao[i]
```

But when I try to write then to a csv with the following code:

```
>>> ofile  = open('teste.csv', "wb")
>>> writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=';')
>>> for i in range(0,len(questao)):
...  writer.writerow(questao[i])
```

I get the following output in test.csv (it's a sample, not from the same elements above):

```
A; ;t;i;t;u;l;a;‡;Æ;o; ;g;e;n;‚;r;i;c;a; ;d;e; ;A;d;m;i;n;i;s;t;r;a;‡;Æ;o; ;P;£;b;l;i;c;a;,; ;u;s;a;d;a; ;p;e;l;o; ;l;e;g;i;s;l;a;d;o;r; ;c;o;n;s;t;i;t;u;i;n;t;e; ;d;e; ;1;9;8;8;,; ;a;o; ;t;r;a;t;a;r; ;d;a; ;O;r;g;a;n;i;z;a;‡;Æ;o; ;d;o; ;E;s;t;a;d;o;,; ;p;a;r;a; ;e;f;e;i;t;o; ;d;e; ;s;u;j;e;i;‡;Æ;o; ;d;o;s; ;s;e;u;s; ;a;t;o;s; ;…; ;o;b;e;d;i;ˆ;n;c;i;a; ;d;e; ;d;e;t;e;r;m;i;n;a;d;o;s; ;p;r;i;n;c;¡;p;i;o;s; ;f;u;n;d;a;m;e;n;t;a;i;s; ;e; ;…; ;o;b;s;e;r;v;ƒ;n;c;i;a; ;d;e; ;o;u;t;r;a;s; ;e;x;i;g;ˆ;n;c;i;a;s;,; ;r;e;s;t;r;i;‡;ä;e;s; ;o;u; ;l;i;m;i;t;a;‡;ä;e;s; ;a;l;i; ;d;e;c;l;i;n;a;d;a;s;,; ;a;b;r;a;n;g;e; ;e; ;a;l;c;a;n;‡;a; ;
```

Comment: How is questao initialized? if it is a `str` type, your iterator will iterate over the individual characters. try using `split()`

Comment: You are trying to `writerow` a `str`, which is an iterable. You should `writerow` a `list` of `str`s instead. Try `writerow(questao)` instead of `writerow(questao[i])` and see what happens

Comment: @karthikr can you give me an example?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I tried and I received this error: csv.Error: sequence expected

Comment: Please edit `questao` into your post

Comment: @inspectorG4dget what? I'm sorry, didn't get what you mean

Comment: Edit your post to show the value of `questao`

Comment: the values of questao are already in the first paragraph of my question. I printed it with questao[i]

Comment: Alright. You have also posted a sample from output.csv. What is the desired output for that sample?

Answer (score 1):

The code is outputting the expected output. If you iterate over a string in Python, you get the individual characters. You might have been after a split by paragraph (by line), or maybe by space. In either case, this should help:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

```
mystring.split(str.split("\n"));
```

Or similar is maybe what you're after. (Sometimes \r\n. Someone probably has a platform independent solution)

Comment: I tried and got this: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Did you run split on a string or on a dict?

Comment: I run on questao, which is a dict, since I started it as questao = {} as I mentioned in my question

Comment: Surely you have the data in a strong format somewhere further up your code?